# Prevent expandable panel

Tags: extjs, accordion, extjs4.2

I have an accordion layout in a window. I don't want the second panel to be expanded. 
I've tried with

```
var intermodPanel = {
                    xtype : 'panel',
                    title : 'unexpandable panel',
                    listeners : {
                        beforeactivate : function(){
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                }
```

But it doesn't work. I'm working on Extjs 4.2.

[image: accordion layout]

Also, my "plus" and "minus" icons at the right of the header are not displayed, is there something I've missed?

```
 var winPort = Ext.create('widget.window', {
                    id: 'win' + pointcode,
                    title: 'a Window'  ,
                    autoScroll: true,
                    header: {
                        titlePosition: 2,
                        titleAlign: 'center'
                    },

                    closable: true,
                    closeAction: 'hide',
                    width: 822,
                    height: 533,
                    layout: 'accordion',
                    layoutConfig : {
                        animate : true
                    },
                   items : [expandablePanel, unexpandablePanel, expandablePanel]
                }).show();
```

Thank you

Comment: I can see plus and minus in this http://jsfiddle.net/1n1uz80h/ with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that `beforeactivate` is only valid for Card layout, not for accordion layout: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-event-beforeactivate

So, how to make an accordion layout that prevents a card from being opened?

Easy as cake: Just use the correct event.

```
listeners : {
    beforeexpand : function(){
        return false;
    }
}
```